# How to use 2 external monitors, #1 duplicating laptop screen and #2 extending Win7 desktop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, multiple-monitors

I have a Lenovo W520 laptop running Windows 7, and 2 external monitors. My docking station supports this; I can have a 3-monitor desktop (laptop + 2 monitors) and it works fine. They are all 1920x1200.

I would like to have a 2-monitor desktop:

- monitor #1 duplicates laptop screen
- monitor #2 extends desktop

Is there a way to do this? The Control Panel → Display doesn't seem to support this option:

[image]

and if I choose Duplicate desktop on 2 and 3, then monitors 2 and 3 show the same thing, and the menu changes:

[image]

Comment: It's possible in Windows 10 ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZYzc.png)), are you sure you don't have these options? I'm not sure when they were added.